# Survival analysis with acute/dynamic predictors

Tags: regression, survival

I am looking for a family/class of regression that is able to handle survival-like data, however the predictors are not constant for each subject during the analysis window.

I suspect such a thing exists, but there may be problems with the approach that make it intractable that I am not appreciating, or I may simply not know what to *call* such an analysis.

I have in mind a situation where a *predictor* (not the outcome) represents an event:

1. The event can happen never, once, or more than once.
2. The event has an impact on the risk of the dependent variable.
3. The impact of the event on risk is causative, only impacting risk post-event.
4. We don't care about events that occur after the outcome, since this is a survival analysis.

Of course a traditional survival analysis can handle this situation if we start time at the event time, and compare to some other group where no event happens, but such an approach cannot handle subjects where events can occur more than once.

Comment: I think the term you are looking for is [time varying covariate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time-varying_covariate)

Comment: @CliffAB Indeed; in fact this seems like it is quite normal in Cox regression. Odd that I wasn't able to find this sooner. Thank you.